# Thread cancellation (pthread) & C++

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, pthreads, cancellation

I'm writing MT program  for Linux in C++ and I want to know how thread cancellation is performed.

As far as I understand when thread is cancelled cleanup functions are called inside thread's function and the thread's function is forced to exit. This mean two things:

1. When thread is cancelled it still calls destructors fo all C++ objects created inside thread's function.
2. I can pass to cleanup functions pointers to objects created in thread's function.

Am I right and code below ill work just fine?

---

One more question in code below, when thread is cancelled somewhere in **SECTION A**, **second_thread_cleanup_function()** will be called first, right?

```
class SomeObject
{
    public:
        ~SimpleObject (void); // <- free dynamically allocated memory

        void finalize (void);

        // ...
}

void first_thread_cleanup_function (void* argument)
{
    SomeObject* object (argument);

    object->finalize ();
}

void second_thread_cleanup_function (void* argument)
{
    // ... do something ...
}

void* thread_function (viod* argument)
{
    SomeObject object;

    pthread_cleanup_push (first_thread_cleanup_function, &object);

    // ... some code ...

    pthread_cleanup_push (second_thread_cleanup_function, NULL);
    // ... SECTION A ...
    pthread_cleanup_pop (0);

    // .. some code ...

    pthread_cleanup_pop (1);
}
```

Comment: If coding it in C++, remember RAII: Consider using C++0x std::thread, or C++ boost::thread, or even mimick a graceful exit via an exception (see http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/207100682 for more information).

Comment: I was thinking about it, but I have to do some specific things with threads. I know, that I'm (mostly) reinventing the wheel...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With any modern linux distribution using NPTL (which in practice means any running a 2.6 kernel), NPTL will call destructors and unwind the stack with a pseudo-exception.

In fact NPTL insists on it, by implementing what it calls forced stack unwinding.  You can catch the pseudo-exception with catch(...), but if you do so you must subsequently rethrow it or the whole process will be terminated.

Chris

Answer (score 2):

Destructors will only be called assuming you free allocated objects in the cleanup methods.  Otherwise, no.

And yes, you have the order of cleanup calls in section A correct.

Comment: but destructor of 'object' will be called anyway?

Comment: @Goofy - I assume you mean `object` in `thread_function`.  The answer is no.  `thread_function` will stop at the first cancellation point after you call cancel.  The thread's stack is not unwound, and the only cleanup happens in the cleanup functions.

Comment: Yes, I mean 'object' in 'thread_function'. To be clear - if thread exits normally it unwind stack and call object's destructors?

Comment: If the thread exists normally then it all ends like a normal function call.  So, yes.

Comment: @Donnie It appears that a local object's destructor is called when its thread is cancelled. See my answer.

Comment: Hi @Donnie. I know little about pthread cancellation and am reading SO's [cancellation] tag as part of an effort to start correcting that. I would find a comment clarifying the apparent discrepancy between "The thread's stack is not unwound" (from a comment by you above) and "[modern] NPTL will call destructors and unwind the stack with a pseudo-exception" (@Chris/@SteveEmmerson) helpful. "I don't know" would probably be the most helpful simple answer but anything would be appreciated. TIA.

Comment: @raiph The best thing to do at this point would be experiment on your own.  I wouldn't trust much of anything at this level from a 10 year old thread.

Comment: @Donnie Fair enough. Thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 2):

The assertion that a cancelled thread's stack is not unwound -- resulting in the non-destruction of local objects -- is inconsistent with the assertion by @Chris that the thread's stack is unwound and with the following counter-example:

```
#include <climits>
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>

class Obj {
public:
    Obj()  { std::clog << "Obj() called\n"; }
    ~Obj() { std::clog << "~Obj() called\n"; }
};

static void cleanup(void* arg) {
    std::clog << "cleanup() called\n";
}

static void run() {
    Obj obj{}; // Local object
    pthread_cleanup_push(cleanup, nullptr);
    ::pause(); // Thread cancelled here
    pthread_cleanup_pop(1);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::thread thread([]{run();});
    ::sleep(1);
    ::pthread_cancel(thread.native_handle());
    thread.join();
}
```

When executed, the above program indicates that the local object's destructor is, indeed, called when the thread is cancelled:

```
$ ./a.out 
Obj() called
cleanup() called
~Obj() called
$
```